# Android Studio Error - libpng error: Not a PNG file

Tags: android, png

I'm having an error with Android Studio. Do you guys happen to know how to solve it?

I have already checked if the files exists. They do. I already checked the image format and also resaved to png. I still get the following error. What could it be?

--- The error ---

:app:mergeDebugResources
libpng error: Not a PNG file

Error: Failed to run command:
    C:\Users\Kharlo PC\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio1\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\aapt.exe s -i D:\XfixedOdometer\app\src\main\res\drawable-hdpi\ic_launcher.png -o D:\XfixedOdometer\app\build\intermediates\res\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\ic_launcher.png

Error Code:
    42

Output:
    libpng error: Not a PNG file

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well... it's not a PNG file! Or just possibly it's a PNG file but not a supported variant.

If you would like any more info then you will have to upload the file somewhere and then post a link. It's impossible to tell anything more without it.

EDIT: Now that you've uploaded the file, I can see that it's a JPEG! It has a `.png` extension, but it's not a PNG file.

Comment: I checked its mime type online. It says it's a PNG. Did I missed anything?

Comment: Okay.. so I used a PHP function, yes it's a JPEG! Sorry about that! Thanks!

Comment: @KarloKokkak something online might get its mime type from the extension, in which case it would be fooled into thinking it was a PNG. The link you gave serves it with a mime type of `image/png`. But if you examine the binary data in the file, you'll see it is really a jpeg.

Comment: @KarloKokkak please click to accept the answer if it  was helpful!

Comment: I have xml and png files in my drawable, how can I check if its not a PNG file?

Answer (score 0):

Although there can be various reasons for this error , i.e **Can't resolve symbol R**

But In particular, If the problem is saying **Not a PNG file**

*My Case*

For me ,it was a **jpeg** file that I had saved with extension **.png**
which was the root cause

**Solution**

remove that jpeg image from your **res/drawable** folder

***Note***
renaming a jpeg to png doesn't mean it is a png in android studio...
so get rid of that jpeg image

rebuild..

voila.. it works

hope it helps :)